# should i get a better router if i lag when someone is streaming youtube

Tags: wireless-networking, router, streaming, gaming, netflix

my internet provider is TM , a malaysian internet provider. they gave us a free router . its a D-Link DIR-615 , i live in my parents house. we have around 5 people here. me and my 2 other bros game alot , and when we game we tend to lag when someone is streaming youtube. we all use WiFi, my parents only use the internet for Netflix , and they're connected to LAN . is there a way to game and stream at the same time with no lag? should i get a better router?

Comment: A better router won’t improve your latency or downloading speeds (which low speeds cause lag on YouTube)

Comment: so what should i do? get a better plan from the internet provider?

Answer (score 0):

If lag increases when bandwidth is filled, it means one or more pieces of networking equipment involved in your internet connection has a well-known bug called bufferbloat. Using a bufferbloat aware router at the head of your network, and making it use traffic shaping so it becomes a slight bottleneck (so it can have its anti-bufferbloat algorithms kick in before bufferbloat happens anywhere else) would probably help.